# AppEngine 1.9.2 + Objectify 4.1.2 = huge auto-generated IDs

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have an AppEngine Project which uses Objectify.

- I just upgraded my AppEngine SDK => 1.9.2
- And I migrated from Objectify 3.1 to 4.1.2

Before that switch, the generated IDs of my entities in the DataStore where in that range :

- id = 84001
- id = 86001 etc.

Now they are like this :

- id = 5105650963054592
- id = 5649050225344512 etc.

The previous IDs were already a bit strange (big gaps) but it seems normal, now there might be something wrong.

Where could be the problem ?

- My code / Config ?
- Objectify ?
- DataStore ?
- Nothing, it's normal

Nb : I don't set the ID (type Long) before calling ofy().save().entity(entity).now().

Thanks for your help.

Pierre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. App Engine switched to long and random auto-generated IDs in order to reduce contention (and, therefore, improve the performance) in the Datastore.

> The Datastore can be configured to generate auto IDs using two
> different auto id policies: The default policy generates a random
> sequence of IDs that are approximately uniformly distributed. Each ID
> can be up to 16 digits long. The legacy policy creates a sequence of
> non-consecutive smaller integer IDs.
>
> Source: [Entities, Properties, and Keys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities)

Comment: A very important question: are the generated IDs unique? I haven't found any information about this in the official documentation.

Comment: IDs are unique except that child entities may have the same IDs if they belong to different parent entities. For example, if you have an entity "user" with no ancestors, every entity "user" will have a unique ID. If you also have an entity "user album", which is a child of "user", then "user album" entities will have unique IDs only within a single "user".